# Oracle 12c: How to resolve a bad bind variable error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have this table named, MOTOR_PRODUCTS, where it needs to store an image. I have written a PL/SQL code and when I already compile it, an error appears that says **'bad bind variable 'MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_image'**. How to resolve this kind of error? Thank you to people who will help me.

Here with my PL/SQL code:

```
Declare A number;
Begin
IF
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_ID IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_NAME IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_YEAR IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_COLOR IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_PRICE IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_WARRANTY_PERIOD IS NULL OR
 :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_DESCRIPTION IS NULL
 THEN A:= SHOW_ALERT ('ALERT_FILLUP');

ELSE
 INSERT INTO MOTOR_PRODUCTS (motor_id, motor_name, category_id, motor_year, motor_color, motor_price, motor_description, motor_features, motor_warranty_period, motor_specifications, motor_image)
 VALUES (:MOTOR_PRODUCTS.category_id||:MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_id,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_name,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.category_id,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_year,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_color,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_price,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_description,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_features,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_warranty_period,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_specifications,
  :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.motor_image);

  FORMS_DDL('COMMIT');
  A := SHOW_ALERT('ALERT_SAVE');
END IF;

End;
```

Comment: i think you don't have an item `motor_image` in the `motor_products` block. By the way, you don't need  to use `FORMS_DDL` for `commit`, just use `commit` instead.

Comment: hi! @BarbarosÖzhan, I have a motor_image item in my motor_products block but still, I receive this kind of error.

Comment: what are the data types of motor_image in the table and in the block?

Comment: My guess is that MOTOR_IMAGE is BLOB column.  If that's the case, then you don't just insert them directly.  Typically you'll need to insert an empty_bloc and use the subsequent lob located to piecemeal read the image.  If that image is on your local file system, then you'll probably need something like webutil.